# HttpClient has very large response time on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

I have followed the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos to make Xamarin Android application support TLS 1.2

When I call rest service, It takes 10+ seconds from Xamarin Android while 2 seconds from Xamarin IOS project.

Both project uses same PLC HttpClient code to call same service.

**Code:**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);
response = await client.SendAsync(request);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Line **response = await client.SendAsync(request);** takes considerable amount of time to execute as mentioned above.

Raising this issue as it has considerable difference between IOS & Android environment in Xamarin.

Comment: Where exactly is the delay, awaiting `SendAsync` or `ReadAsStringAsync`?

Comment: delay in executing line response = await client.SendAsync(request);

Comment: what if you try `SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)`, is it still where the delay is then?

Comment: it had not made any difference. :
(

Comment: Yes on same line

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug then

Comment: Did you try using WebClient instead of HttpClient? I find it fast enough (2-3 sec to retrieve data)